# The variables from the form is not passed to php

Tags: php

I have this form with which I am trying to take some user entered variables and pass them to calculate.php for counting and showing the result.

#### calculate.html

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Calculation Form</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="calculate.php">
<P>Value 1: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="vall" SIZE=10></P>
<P>Value 2: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="val2" SIZE=10></P>

<P>Calculation:<br>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="calc" VALUE="add"> add<br>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="calc" VALUE="subtract"> subtract<br>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="calc" VALUE="multiply"> multiply<br>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="calc" VALUE="divide"> divide</P>


<P><INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="submit" VALUE="Calculate"></P>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

#### calculate.php:

```
        <?
if (($_POST["vall"] == "") || ($_POST["val2"] == "") || ($_POST["calc"] =="")) {
    header("Location: http://localhost/calculate.html");
exit;
}

if ($_POST["calc"] == "add") {
   $result = $_POST["vall"] + $_POST["val2"];
} else if ($_POST["calc"] == "subtract") {
   $result = $_POST["vall"] - $_POST["val2"];
} else if ($_POST["calc"] == "multiply") {
   $result = $_POST["vall"] * $_POST["val2"];
} else if ($_POST["calc"] == "divide") {
   $result = $_POST["vall"] / $_POST["val2"];
}

?>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Calculation Result</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<P>The result of the calculation is: <? echo $result; ?></P>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

can anybody say where is my mistake as I get only the: The result of the calculation is:

Comment: Use quotes for the array index, like $_POST['calc'], and first check if you actually have a POST request. Also, you should always have errors enabled and displayable

Comment: " you should always have errors enabled and displayable" - you mean I should implement in my code to always show errors?

Comment: In your development environment, yes, on production, no (just log them instead). I refer to language erros, not UX messages.
Never develop without being shown, in a way or another (output on the screen, log file, whatever), any warning/error (like an "Undefined constant 'val1', assuming 'val1' on line....")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could just a mistype here, but - besides all that everyone else said, **you forgot to close** the `</form>` tag

```
<INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="calc" VALUE="divide"> divide</P>

<P><INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="submit" VALUE="Calculate"></P>

</FORM> <!-- MISSING -->

</BODY>
```

I would also check for a POST request before processing:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
   // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You missed `"`s in array index in all the `$_POST[]`, so you need to add `""`.

```
<?
if (($_POST["vall"] == "") || ($_POST["val2"] == "") || ($_POST["calc"] =="")) {
    header("Location: http://localhost/calculate.html");
exit;
}

if ($_POST["calc"] == "add") {
   $result = $ POST[vall] + $_POST[val2];

} else if ($_POST["calc"] == "subtract") {
   $result = $_POST["vall"] - $_POST["val2"];
} else if ($_POST["calc"] == "multiply") {
   $result = $_POST["vall"] * $_POST["val2"];
} else if ($_POST["calc"] == "divide") {
   $result = $_POST["vall"] / $_POST["val2"];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

These `$_POST[vall]` need to be `$_POST['vall']`. The string literal `vall` is the key.

Comment: Indeed that is incorrect usage as `The key can either be an integer or a string.` ([PHP Arrays Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)), but not necessarily the problem here, as PHP automatically tries to convert a missing constant name to a string and throws a notice: `Notice: Use of undefined constant val1 - assumed 'val1'`

Comment: I updated the code, but it seems it was not the case with the "" as I still have no errors and no result displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake on line 8 in your calculate.php:

```
$result = $ POST[vall] + $_POST[val2];
```

should be:

```
$result = $_POST["vall"] + $_POST["val2"];
```

And take into account previous answers

Comment: I noticed it. Thanks! But still I have no result.